# Recursive Array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I already spent some hours figuring this one out but without any usable result.
Maybe someone could help me out with this one, i want to use it inside a class so
I want to build a method with as input the array and as output the rebuild array

I have this array:

```
     Array
     (
         [0] => Array
             (
                 [5] => 0-5
                 [8] => 0-8
                 [9] => 0-9
                 [10] => 0-10
             )

         [10] => Array
             (
                 [11] => 10-11
                 [12] => 10-12
             )

         [11] => Array
             (
                 [13] => 11-13
             )

         [12] => Array
             (
                 [14] => 12-14
             )

     )
```

And this array should be transformed to this one:

```
     Array
     (
         [0] => 0-5
         [1] => 0-8
         [2] => 0-9
         [3] => Array
             (
                 [0] => 0-10
                 [1] => Array
                     (
                         [0] => 10-11
                         [1] => Array
                             (
                                 [0] => 11-13
                             )

                         [2] => 10-12
                         [3] => Array
                             (
                                 [0] => 12-14
                             )

                     )

             )

     )
```

EDIT1: The values of the examples are also arrays en with this I want to process some actions. For example 0-9 is one action and stops but 0-10 has children. If 0-10 is finished and return true or false the next child is fired. If true 10-11 else 10-12. It is my first time on this forum sorry for any inconvenience

EDIT2: Maybe this example helps, this is the posted string in JSON. I have a couple of rules in the database wich will help to pick the right article for the job.

```
    $postdata = '{"next":false, 
                  "data":{"name":"patrick",
                          "etc":"etc",
                         "MotionDetection":"yes",
                         "nameOfTheRoom": ["Room1","Room2","Room3"],  
                         "havePets":"yes"}';

 Array
 (
     [0] => 0-5
     [1] => 0-8
     [2] => 0-9
     [3] => Array
         (
             [0] => "yes" // MotionDetection
             [1] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => "yes" // Have Pets
                     [1] => Array
                         (
                             [0] => "CountRecords" // Count nameOfTheRoom
                             [1] => "insertArticle A"
                         )

                     [2] => "No" // Have Pets
                     [3] => Array
                         (
                             [0] => "CountRecords" // Count nameOfTheRoom
                             [1] => "insertArticle B"
                         )

                 )

         )

 )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: And what actually is your question?

Comment: What is your logic to convert this array?

Comment: Try code from my answer. Hope it suits your needs. I really don't understand why 0-10 is placed on new level and 10-11 and 10-12 are on the same levels (without creating new).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function transform_arr(&$newarr, &$arr)
{
  if(count($newarr) == 0)
  {
    if(!isset($arr[0]))
    {
       return;
    }

    $newarr = $arr[0];
  }

  $newarr2 = array();
  $k = 0;
  foreach( $newarr as $i => $value )
  {
     if( isset($arr[$i]) )
     {
       $newarr2[$k++] = $value;
       $newarr2[$k++] = $arr[$i];

       if(is_array($newarr2[$k - 1])) transform_arr($newarr2[$k - 1], $arr);
     }
     else
     {
       $newarr2[$k++] = $value;
     }
  }
  $newarr = $newarr2;
}

$arr = array( 
  0 => array( 5=> '0-5', 8 => '0-8', 9 => '0-9', 10 => '0-10'),
  10 => array( 11 => '10-11', 12 => '10-12'),
  11 => array( 13 => '11-13'),
  12 => array( 14 => '12-14') );

$newarr = array();
transform_arr($newarr, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
echo '<br/>';
var_dump($newarr);
```

Result:

```
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [5]=>
    string(3) "0-5"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0-8"
    [9]=>
    string(3) "0-9"
    [10]=>
    string(4) "0-10"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    [11]=>
    string(5) "10-11"
    [12]=>
    string(5) "10-12"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(1) {
    [13]=>
    string(5) "11-13"
  }
  [12]=>
  array(1) {
    [14]=>
    string(5) "12-14"
  }
}

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "0-5"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "0-8"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "0-9"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "0-10"
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "10-11"
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "11-13"
    }
    [2]=>
    string(5) "10-12"
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "12-14"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is almost what I need. Your code produces I differtent result than my example. Tnx A lot for your trouble!!

Comment: If you explain your array generation logic fully, I will try to fix solution.

Comment: Its like a chain of reactions, maybe the whole idea is wrong??? in Pseudocode if motiondetection==true then count the number of rooms AND ask do you have Pets, if yes than add acticle A*rooms, else add Article B*rooms.

Comment: This is an example off the database table. pcwsq_formaction_id represents an action like (doMail, doMessage, addArticle) http://vanwijkp.home.xs4all.nl/example.jpg (bewegingsdetectie == motiondetection)(huisdieren == pets)(ruimtenaam == roomid)

Comment: Ok. In my view output of my implementation corresponds to table on example.jpg. What is wrong in your view?

Comment: See vanwijkp.home.xs4all.nl/example2.jpg array no 4 should be the action of number 3. The action in the array is a method that is called or if not the next link in the chain. Do you think this approach is the right one?

Comment: Sorry. Don't understand. My view: 5,8,9,10 has parent 0, so they are on level 0; 11,12 have parent 10, so they are on level 1 (array right after parent of them - right after 0-10 (value right after key 10)); 13 has parent 11, so it is on level 2 right after 10-11 (value with key 11); the same with 14 with parent 12 (which level is 1) so it is on level 2 right after 10-12 (with key value 12).